# Tools for Searching a complete solution for IDisposable objects that haven't been disposed

Tags: c#, dispose

As most of us know, in order to manage memory well in .net it is good practice to always call Dispose() on objects that implement IDisposable. However, when writing a lot of code on a daily basis it can be easy to forget to do this.

Does anybody know of a tool that searches through a c# solution and finds all the places where a disposable object hasn't been disposed? I can see there being cases where this doesn't work when object likes bitmaps are assigned to properties but even a more basic checker would have value.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: If you make it a habit to check if an object is disposable, you'll start to find it hard to forget. I almost always try to wrap something in a using block and if the compiler complains that the object doesn't implement IDisposable, then I remove it. It's better to err that way. Also, a good habit to get into when you use a disposable object as an object level instance variable, is to immediately write the disposing/clean up code as soon as you add the object to your code. That being said a tool would be a nice safety net.

Comment: I just saw three dancing unicorns when I upvoted this question. Sweet!

Comment: Yeah for sure Jason, but then you find yourself in the middle of using some new class you haven't touched before like a GraphicsPath or something arbitrary and you move on to the next deadline. This is something not to take away from due diligence but as you said as a safety net before releasing code.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found that Visual Studio 2010 can do exactly what I was looking for. To get the behaviour do the following:

- Create a new code analysis ruleset as described in [How to: Create a Custom Rule Set](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264974.aspx)
- Add the following rules to your rules set:

  - Dispose objects before losing scope
  - Do not dispose objects multiple times
  - Disposable fields should be disposed
  - Dispose methods should call base class dispose

Or just run them as part of your general code analysis rules. It won't catch everything but its a better safety net than no safety net.

Comment: This is very effective and has the added bonus of catching problems at compile time rather than runtime.  +1

Comment: This is good indeed. Since I don't have MSVS 2010 Ultimate (and didn't know about the Code Analysis feature at all) I coded my own solution instead: [EyeDisposable](https://github.com/kizzx2/EyeDisposable). I don't know how reliable MSVS 2010 is but I used a runtime check approach so maybe it's something want to try :p

Comment: That options window is depreciated. `NOTE: This property page has been deprecated and will be removed in a future product release.`  Can you say any alternative? thanks

Answer (score 1):

My favorite memory profiler is [Ants Profiler from Redgate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-performance-profiler/). It's pretty simple to use, and they have lots of tutorials to get you started. Best thing is the 14 day free trial, so you can try it out and make sure it's going to work for you before you buy it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Brandon but thats not really what I am looking for, I am looking for a code analyzer, that searches through a project, generates a report and says in "file x, line y, object foo was never disposed"

Comment: Sounds cool, haven't heard of a static code analysis tool that can do that...might not be too accurate given that you can't predict run-time conditions, but the concept is cool.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you're using the recommended pattern of suppressing finalization when Dispose is invoked manually, you can spot these errors is by adding a bit of code to tell you whenever Dispose is invoked on the finalizer thread.

```
~MyClass()
{  
     Dispose( false );
     Console.WriteLine( "Argh, release me! I want better co-workers!" );
}

public Dispose()
{  
     Dispose( true );
     GC.SuppressFinalization( this );
}

public Dispose( bool invokedByDeveloper )
{  
     if( invokedByDeveloper )
         // free managed resources

     // free unmanaged resources
}
```

Using a memory profiler as suggested by BrandonZeider is also an option. ANTS is a great, albeit somewhat pricey, profiler. Jetbrains also make a good profiler, and you can try both for 30 days without buying.

Comment: Thanks Morten, I actually do stuff like that, where I get caught up is when I forget on framework classes. Bitmaps for instance will literally kill your app if you forget and when there are hundreds of thousands of lines it's easy to do. p.s. I didn't down vote you

Comment: You could consider creating wrapper classes around the framework classes, and simply expose the underlying resource as a property. This allows you to use the same technique even when you didn't author the classes or they happen to be sealed.

Comment: Too late for that I am afraid. Would be great to find the right tool, if not I might just write it.

Comment: I should add that using a memory profiler really is a snap and well worth the investment, so do consider that before spending too much time on any manual solutions.

Comment: There are reasons why these tools do not exist, or rather, why they are called memory profilers and not "here's your bug"-tools ;) You cannot tell the correct behavior just from looking at the source except for the simple cases (which VS code analysis or FxCop can find for you), so for anything moderately complex a profiler is needed.

Comment: I do that to but that is a reactive solution to a memory problem that exists rather than the proactive one I am looking for to solve the problem before I need to fire up ants and try to track on down from several hundred megabytes of allocated memory

Comment: Well, if you do come up with a tool to locate these with any degree of reliability, give Red Gate or Microsoft a call - I'm pretty sure you could get a new job and a raise ;)

Comment: I just love it when someone downvotes without commenting why.

Comment: Actually Morten, these tools do exist, they fall into a category called static code analysis. One such tool is FXCop, Resharper also does this to some extent.

Comment: As mentioned above, although these tools exist they can only detect simple scenarios. For instance, FxCop only warns you when a method creates an IDisposable without disposing it. If you return the created object for disposal at some later time it provides no help.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best way to stop a problem like this in its tracks is to be disposed "obsessed". Think about being efficient by doing things like planning when and where in your code your objects can be disposed, and then dispose them. If you work in a team, bring up disposal to them.

If the scope of your disposable object is short lived and maybe contained in one small part of a method somewhere, wrap it with a using so it's guaranteed to be disposed. I use using (is that grammatically correct?) any chance I get.

Obviously these aren't automated suggestions and won't always work but it's not hard to be in the right mindset and learn best practices that you can apply to everyday work. That's my two cents.